# Problems with a closing bracket in my code

Tags: jquery, sockets, arguments

i have a question about a syntax error (i guess) in my Code. While testing it i suddenly got the message that i have a missing bracket in my lines. Here is what it looks like. Actually im trying to get informations from my database and append them to my front-end via socket.io. The error is in this code is on line 3.

```
socket.on('matchoverview', function(data){

  var $item1 = $("<div class='grid-item'><div class='row justify-content-md-center'><div class='col col-lg-1'></div><div class='col-lg-10'><div class='row'><div class='col-sm-3'><h3 id='insertteam1'><button id="" type='button' class='btn btn-dark'>Dark</button>" + data.teamonename + "</h3></div><div class='col-sm-3'><h3 id='insertpic1'>" + '<img id="logo" src=' + data.onelogo + '></img>' + "</h3></div><div class='col-sm-2'><h3 id='insertodd1'>" + data.teamoneodd + "</h3></div><div class='col-sm-2'><h3 id='insertclock'>" + data.time + "</h3></div><div class='col-sm-3'><h3 id='insertodd2'>" + data.teamtwoodd + "</h3></div><div class='col-sm-3'><h3 id='insertpic2'>" + '<img id="logo" src=' + data.twologo + '></img>' + "</h3></div><div class='col-sm-2'><h3 id='inserteam2'>" + data.teamtwoname + "</h3></div><div class='col-sm-2'><h3 id='inserttwitch'>" + data.twitchlink + "</h3></div></div></div></div></div>").click(function() {
    console.log('Jo!');
  });

  var $item2 = $("<div class='grid-item'><div class='row justify-content-md-center'><div class='col col-lg-1'></div><div class='col-lg-10'><div class='row'><div class='col-sm-3'><h3 id='insertteam1'><button id="" type='button' class='btn btn-dark'>Dark</button>" + data.teamonename + "</h3></div><div class='col-sm-3'><h3 id='insertpic1'>" + '<img id="logo" src=' + data.onelogo + '></img>' + "</h3></div><div class='col-sm-2'><h3 id='insertodd1'>" + data.teamoneodd + "</h3></div><div class='col-sm-2'><h3 id='insertclock'>" + data.time + "</h3></div><div class='col-sm-3'><h3 id='insertodd2'>" + data.teamtwoodd + "</h3></div><div class='col-sm-3'><h3 id='insertpic2'>" + '<img id="logo" src=' + data.twologo + '></img>' + "</h3></div><div class='col-sm-2'><h3 id='inserteam2'>" + data.teamtwoname + "</h3></div><div class='col-sm-2'><h3 id='inserttwitch'>" + data.twitchlink + "</h3></div></div></div></div></div>").click(function() {
    console.log('Jo!');
  });

  $grid2.append( $item1 ).masonry( 'appended', $item1 );
  $grid2.append( $item2 ).masonry( 'appended', $item2 );

});
```

Errorcode:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list
```

Thanks in advance and have a nice day

Comment: That's not a very readable way to insert HTML. Your string delimiters are `"` but you have `button id=""` inside.

Comment: <button id="" type='button' class='btn btn-dark'>Dark</button> please define id. Hope it will help you to identify problem!

Comment: True that, should have used ' ' then

Comment: @rahulmistry That did it. It works and error code is gone. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure your string delimiters are enclosed and placed properly.

Issue on "" and ''

```
<button id=""
```

to

```
<button id=''
```

and your

```
src='+variable+'
```

must be

```
src='" +variable+ "'
```

Thanks!

Comment: Nice to know, appreciated